# Unable to push to remote repo/'Push to' button is grayed out

Tags: git, visual-studio, git-push

I've already successfully committed to my local repo,
[image]

but when I go to push to remote the button is grayed out.
[image]

I tried using command prompt instead but no luck: it says I am up to date. I last pushed successfully just a few days ago. Any particular reason why this might be?

Answer (score 0):

If a git fetch + git status confirms you are up-to-date, try and reload VSCode (Open the command palette (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>) and execute the command `>Reload Window`) to see if the issue persists.

VSCode should synchronize with your local repository state.

Make sure to add [GitLens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens) as one of your installed extensions, as it provides more information on those remote repositories.